Best practices for mocking an endpoint and checking if this call happened
I am currently using Playwright to test an application. For this purpose, I need to mock calls to my backend because the backend is not running during the tests, and I don’t want the tests to hit the real backend.
To achieve this, I am using page.route to mock the calls. At the beginning of my tests, I initialize a variable called requests, which is an array. Whenever page.route matches a route of interest, I add the request from the page.route function to this array:
 test(`my test test`, async ({
    page,
  }) => {
    const response = [...];
    let requests: Request[] = [];
    await page.route("**/api/endpoint**", (route, request) => {
      if(request.method() == "POST") {
        requests.push(request);
      }
      route.fulfill({
        status: 200,
        contentType: "application/json",
        body: JSON.stringify(response),
      });
    });
    
    // Doing my test stuff
     ...

    // check if calls was successfully done
    expect(requests).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(requests[0].postDataJSON()).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(requests[0].postDataJSON()).toBe({...});

At the end of the test, I need to verify that the mocked call was actually made during the test execution. I check whether the array is empty or not to determine if the call was triggered by the actions performed in my test.
However, I occasionally encounter an issue where the array does not contain the expected request after performing the action that should trigger the call. It seems that the test completes faster than the application sends out the request. To handle this, I am also using page.waitForResponse:
 test(`my test test`, async ({
    page,
  }) => {
     ...
      // STUFF
      
    const [request] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForRequest(
      request =>
        request.url().includes("/api/endpoint") &&
        request.method() === "POST",
    ),
    button.click(), // this button click triggers the /api/endpoint call
  ]);
    // check if calls was successfully done
    expect(requests).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(requests[0].postDataJSON()).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(requests[0].postDataJSON()).toBe({...});

Can I streamline this process by omitting certain steps to avoid redundancy in my test? What are the best practices to achieve the goal of verifying that the mocked backend call was made?

What do you want to streamline, what would be the redundancy? I don't see anything to remove without reducing the scope of the test.

Isn't it a better way to remove the requests array and somehow use the waitForRequest call to validate the requests?

Your code shows waitForRequest, not waitForResponse. You want the latter, not the former. I agree with Moustapha, there's nothing obvious to streamline here, and without a [mcve] and big chunks of the code elided by // STUFF, there's not much to offer other than maybe try using a length poll on the response array, which would avoid the repeated waitForResponses.

What exactly do you mean with "length poll" ?

One frustrating pattern is having to define the endpoint multiple times:

Initially, to mock the response.
Again, before the frontend action takes place.
Finally, to add a wait after the action.

It's particularly annoying to use page.waitForResponse before performing the frontend action...
